# 'this' in nested function

Tags: javascript, this

```
   var EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;
        var Counter = function (init) {
            this.increment = function () {
                init++;
                this.emit('incremented', init);
            }
        }
        Counter.prototype = new EventEmitter();
        var counter = new Counter(10);
        var callback = function (count) {
            console.log(count);
        }
        counter.addListener('incremented', callback);

        counter.increment(); // 11
        counter.increment(); // 12
```

In the sample above, the `this` in `this.increment` refers to counter object. What does the this in`this.emit` refer to? Is it the increment object or counter? And how exactly is emit executed?

Comment: Adding a simple `console.log(this)` will tell you that it is the `Counter` object

Comment: What `this` refers to depends on how `this.increment` is called. What exactly do you mean by "increment object"?

Comment: If `this` is the Counter instance, then `this.emit` will refer to the `emit` method that is inherited from the `EventEmitter.prototype`.

Answer (score 0):

The `this` you ask about will be an object that has the context of the function that eventually invokes the `this.increment` function, since `this.increment` will be called a simple function rather than as an object instantiation with the `new` keyword.

> In most cases, the value of this is determined by how a function is
>   called.
>
> Inside a function, the value of this depends on how the function is
>   called.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Comment: Please don't call it "scope" - that's a term reserved for the *variable* scope. Most people go by "(invocation) context", the technical term is (unfortunately) just "thisArg".

Comment: @Bergi good point, rather than scope I changed it to "object that has the context"

Answer (score 0):

When you define anything directly on the Object.prototype, it's inherited by all objects. Maybe anywhere on the code there's a definition like:

```
Object.prototype.emit = function(stringValue, function(){});
```

Comment: Except on objects that override it, such as `EventEmitter`s.

Comment: Completing my answer: to my knowledge refers directly to the increment object.

Comment: What is an "increment object"? You don't mean the `increment` function, do you?

Comment: Sometimes javascript can be really confusing, I mean the increment object which in this case it's a function as well. From the moment you refers to 'this' which implies a context you're a dealing with an object, but you can simply disregard my answer.

Comment: Well but then you're wrong. In none of the functions the OP calls does `this` refer to a function object.

Answer (score 0):

```
A= function(){ 
  this.name = 'test';
  this.show = function(){
    console.log(this);
  }
  console.log(this);
}

A(); // window
b = new a(); // A
b.show(); // A
c = b.show; //  function(){ console.log(this); }
c();  // window
c.call(1) // Number {[[PrimitiveValue]]: 1}
```

> In most cases, the value of this is determined by how a function is
>   called. It can't be set by assignment during execution, and it may be
>   different each time the function is called.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Answer (score -4):

this.emit refers to increment object.

In JavaScript this always refers to the “owner” of the function we're executing, or rather, to the object that a function is a method of.